# WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80370114 Error: 0x80370114

Tags: command-line, 20.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When trying to install Ubuntu under WSL Windows 11, I'm getting the following error,
no advice on askubuntu.com works for me:

```
Installing, this may take a few minutes...
WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80370114
Error: 0x80370114 Operaci se nepovedlo spustit, proto?e nenÝ nainstalovanß po?adovanß funkce.

Press any key to continue...
```

Comment: OMG, this has done the job: `wsl --set-default-version 1`

Comment: This is a Windows issue, not an Ubuntu one - see for example [Resolving Error: 0x80370114 The operation could not be started because a required feature is not installed.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1187339/resolving-error-0x80370114-the-operation-could-not)